# How to get the relationship of consumer group and topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka 0.10 kafkaConsumer API to get consumers and topic set under consumer subscribed.

Now I can get topics and partitionIds successfully by topiclist method.

To get consumer group data, I'm not found method under KafkaConsumer, but I can get group list from zookeeper by "zookeeper.getChildren(ZkUtils.ConsumersPath(), false);".

My question is how to get the relationship of group and topics.
I know one group can subscribe one or more topics, but I don't know how to get the data by KafkaConsumer API or from zookeeper.

I had tried kafkaConsumer.subscription() but return is an empty list.

what I reference:
https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: What you exactly want? All consumer groups and for each all topics it did subscribe to? Btw: `KafkaConsumer#subscription()` return the subscription of this single consumer -- if you did not subscribe to any topic yet (not sure if you did or not), it will return an empty list of course.

Comment: Did you ever invoke KafkaConsumer.subscribe() or assign() method before calling subscription()?

Comment: Thank you Sax. Sorry for description not so clear. I'm not do subscribe. There is an exist kafka cluster. I just want to get its consume group and each group's related topics. @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: Thank you amethystic. No I didn't invoke subscribe() and assign(). Now I know if never invoke subscribe or assign will get nothing from subscription. Ignore subscribe... I just want to get the exist consumer group and its related topics by API.@amethystic

Comment: I had got the topics under consumer group from zookeeper :zookeeper.getChildren(ZkUtils.ConsumersPath()+"/[groupId]/owners", false);  Thanks all guys!

Answer (score 3):

There is no API in `KafkaConsumer` to get consumer group information. `KafkaConsumer` is designed to consume messages from topics and be part of a consumer group. But nothing else.

On command line, you can use `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to get consumer group information. Internally, it leverages `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` -- you could try to integrate this in your Java code.

You could also got one lever deeper and use non-public APIs (just have a look into the code of `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` to see how it works internally -- however, this is of course fragile if you want to upgrade later on. Non-public APIs can change for a newer version of course.

Comment: Thanks your answer @Matthias J. Sax. I use below code to get consumer group list from kafka server: String[] commands = new String[]{"--list", "--new-consumer", "--bootstrap-server", "hostIP:9092"}; kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(commands); But the "main" function return void, so I can't fetch the result in code. I use kafka 0.10, seems no method can get group list in ConsumerGroupCommand and ConsumerGroupCommand.KafkaConsumerGroupService.

Comment: Yes. It does return void. You need to go one level deeper and extract and use the code that does the actual work. Just calling main is not sufficient. Internally, ConsumerGroupCommand does collect all information an just prints it to stdout. Just look for those parts and try to copy the code to return the required information back to your app.